# Sitecore computed index issue, only index english item value

Tags: computed-field, indexing

**Problem statement**

1) I have a template "Article" with 3 fields 
"Title" - Single line text
"Description" - rich-text
"Category" - drop-link

2) I created a computed field for "category"  to get the "categoryvalue"

3) I created a category, Article item in English version everything worked fine

4) I create the same item in different language say "Thai"

**Issue** - I am always getting "CategoryValue" in English even though I have created "Thai" versions of all the items.

**What I researched**
I came across some blogs which says that "Indexing always run in default language" and also being suggested to use `Sitecore.Globalization.LanguageSwitcher` while writing code for computed index.

**What Ii debug**
While debugging I found that at the time of indexing `Sitecore.Context.Language` is always English 
and after using `LanguageSwitcher` things worked i.e. I am getting language-specific values

**What is want to understand**

1) Is it correct the computed indexes are always executed in English language?

2) Is applying "sitecore.Globalization.LanguageSwitcher " only solution
or is there any configuration which i am missing here?

Code Snippet

Please note I have commented the language switcher via which things are working fine

```
 public override object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        Item item = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        if (item == null || item.Paths.Path.Contains(SearchConstant.StandardValues)) return null;

        GroupedDroplinkField contentTypeField = null;

        if (item.IsDerived(new ID(SearchConstant.BaseArticleTemplateID)) )
        {
            contentTypeField = item.Fields[SearchConstant.ContentTypeField];
        }

        if (contentTypeField == null || contentTypeField.TargetItem == null) return null;

        if (contentTypeField != null && contentTypeField.TargetItem != null)
        //Please note if i dont put LanguageSwitcher then it always give me english content
         //   using (new Sitecore.Globalization.LanguageSwitcher(item.Language.Name))
           // {
                return contentTypeField.TargetItem.Fields[SearchConstant.Name].Value;
            //}

        return null;
    }
```

Code snippet for Multilist field

```
public override object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {

        Item item = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;


        if (item == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        List<string> featuredTagList = null;
        if ((item.IsDerived(new ID(SearchConstant.BaseArticleTemplateID)))
        {
            MultilistField listField = item?.Fields["FeaturedTags"];
            if (listField?.TargetIDs != null && listField.TargetIDs.Length > 0)
            {
                //using (new Sitecore.Globalization.LanguageSwitcher(item.Language.Name))
                //{
                    var listItems = listField.GetItems();
                    featuredTagList = (from listItem in listItems where listItem?.Fields[SearchConstant.Name] != null let fieldValue = listItem.Fields[SearchConstant.Name].Value select !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldValue) ? fieldValue : listItem.Name).ToList();
                //}
            }
        }

        return featuredTagList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code of your computed index field?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I have updated my question with a code sample. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard Sitecore behavior.

`GroupedDroplinkField` is a type inheriting from `LookupField` type.

That field's value is only a Sitecore ID of the target item, without any information about language or anything else.

Your indexable item may use Thai language, but when you call `contentTypeField.TargetItem`, Sitecore gets the item in your current context language, which for Sitecore backend tasks usually is English.

It's the same like you would call there

```
var contentTypeItem = item.Database.GetItem(contentTypeField.TargetID)
```

Sitecore will return English version of the `contentTypeItem`.

Using `LanguageSwitcher` in your scenario is a good idea.

You can also use code like the one below, if you don't like `LanguageSwitcher` in your code:

```
var contentTypeItem = item.Database.GetItem(contentTypeField.TargetID, item.Language);
```

Comment: Does the same thing applies for a multilist field? I have updated the code for multilist field in this case as well I need to use language switcher

Comment: It does. If you're running in a Sitecore context where you haven't specified any language, `MultilistField.GetItems()` will just use the default. If you're running in Sitecore "shell" site context, it will use whichever language is configured for "shell" site.

Comment: So can we conclude saying that for computed index the context language will always be shell language and developers should always take care of Language (via switcher or some other way) in case of a multilingual site?

Comment: It's not necessarily always a shell language. It depends on indexing strategy you choose and on custom code which you can use to change or publish the items which will be indexed after. But the second part of your conclusion is correct: "When it comes to computed index fields, never assume what your language will be. If you're just using `IIndexable item` from the parameter, you will get it in right language. But if you're getting something else from database, tell Sitecore which language should be used".